# Am I scheduling the task every month correctly using node-schedule?

Tags: node.js, date, scheduled-tasks, node-schedule

I want a task to be executed every month on a specific date as soon as it hits the end point `/shcheduleTaskEveryMonth`. Suppose **17th of every month at 4:29pm** evening I want to run a `job/task`.

And this is the code I am trying to achieve this:
Just wanted to be sure if I am doing right please!

**PS.** This end point gets called once user account is created.

```
 router.get('/shcheduleTaskEveryMonth', function (req, res) {

    var schedule = require('node-schedule');
    var dateFormated = new Date(Fri Jan 17 2021 16:29:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time));
    
          var j = schedule.scheduleJob(dateFormated.getMinutes() +' '+dateFormated.getHours()+' '+dateFormated.getDate() + ' * *', function(){
              console.log('Your scheduled job every month');
          });
    });
```

How can I achieve that?

**UPDATE**:
I just want to fit the above code simple wise similar to this:

```
var j = schedule.scheduleJob('42 * * * *', function(){
  console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
```

Since it's a simple and understandable code I am unable to extract and the add the code likewise.
Thanks!

Comment: You can make use of https://crontab.guru to check the timing of your job is correct.

Comment: ya i got that. But my timing units are variables as well not contants like this: scheduleJob(dateFormated.getMinutes() +' '+dateFormated.getHours()+' '+dateFormated.getDate() + ' * *'

So want to know if it will work like this or not?